# Best practice for storing globally required objects in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am starting to develop a GWT application in MVP style (GWTP) and which uses Spring security for authentication and authorization on server side.

In many views of the application, I have to enable or disable controls with respect to a granted authority of the current user. I already have an RPC service which provides access to a userDetailsDto containing all the necessary information.

Now my question: What is the best place to store the user DTO on client side?

Since the user rights are relevant in many presenters, I would have to pass it around everywhere. Alternatively, I could set an RPC service instance in every presenter and requets the user details each time (probably cached on client-side). But i don't like the idea of having a user RPC service in each presenter just for this purpose.

To be honest, I'd rather would prefer a central registry where to put the UserDetails object and which is accessable from anywhere in my app. Is there already such a registry in GWT?

As in my example, you might often be confronted with horizontally used objects. How to deal with them in GWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply store your current user in public static variable. 
It will be accessible from everywhere.

Comment: That's my current solution, indeed. However 1) static variables are problematic when it comes to unit testing and 2) it is hard to decide, which part (class) is responsible for keeping that static instance. A presenter, the RPC service (would mean that I have a dependency to the RPC service in my view object if I want to access the user object from there.

Comment: I store my current user in the ClientFactory implementation, plain simple and adhering to KISS principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Although I am using GIN instead of the client factory, I like this solution. It is clear that this question cannot have a single true answer (stackoverflow even warned me that it could be rejected), so, Riley Lark, if I could mark both answers as "correct", i would do so ;-)

Comment: I faced quite a few issues while storing some kind of data in ClientFactory. Everytime there is a browser refresh the ClientFactory object data is reset, and data is lost.

Answer (score 5):

I inject an "AppState" object into all of the presenters that need to know things like the rights of the user logged in, their preferences, etc. I prefer injection to a public static variable because it feels more controlled, is easier to mock up in tests, and the extra typing forces me to consider whether each object really needs access to the global data.

Comment: Do you mean by injection passing it to the presenter's constructor with GIN's @Inject annotation?

Comment: I actually just pass it to the constructor with plain-old arguments in the constructor definition.  It's not so much extra typing, and I like the behavior when I change something - compile errors at every point that needs to change.  Causes consideration at all the right points, IMHO.